# seems like foreach loop doesnt work

Tags: php, object, foreach

I want to check an object props, but it looks like loop never runs.

```
        $object =   $this->helix->Footer();
        // var_dump($object) ; // the var dump starts with "object(Helix)#118 (9) { ....."
        foreach($object as $prop_name => $prop_val){
           echo $object->$prop_name ;
        }
```

Does anyobody have idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: foreach($object as $prop_name => $prop_val){
            echo $object[$prop_name];
    }

Comment: Are the properties on the object public?

Comment: What is output of echo count($object);?

Comment: @AnupKhandelwal count is "1"

Comment: @Tomdarkness The first line ... " object(Helix)#118 (9) { ["document":"Helix":private]=> object(JDocumentHTML)#155 (32) { ["_links"]=> array(0) { } ["_custom"]=> array(0) { } ["template"]=> string(5) "jm-me" ["baseurl"]=> string(0) "" ["params"]=> ... "

Comment: You can only loop over the public properties. You've only shown the first property "document", and that is private.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function also: php.net/get_object_vars

But the issue can be the same. This function can show only the properties it can see.
It means, if you call it outside the class, then only the public vars. But is you call it inside the class, then "everything". (see the comments on the manual page.)